# angularjs - interceptor getting empty statusText

Tags: angularjs

Im using an **interceptor globally** for the app. It catches specific responses from the server to react properly to those.

I want to check the `statusText`. **When getting the error response in the interceptor, the `status` is 401 but the `statusText` is "" (empty string)**.

I have not update angular library and we work with **angular 1.4.7**.

Anyone knows any reason why I would not get statusText in the interceptor?

```
var unauthorizedAccessInterceptorFactory =
    ['$rootScope', '$q', '$injector',
    function($rootScope, $q, $injector)
    {
        var unauthorizedAccessInterceptor = {
            responseError: function(operation)
            {
                if(operation.status == '401' && operation.statusText === NOT_AUTHORIZED)
                {
                   ....
                }
            }
        }
    }
}];
```

Implementation of the api doing the call:

```
this.update = function(data){
    var res = $resource(BASE_URL + '/collection/:id',{'id': data._id},  
    {
        put:{
            method:'PUT',
            withCredentials: true
        }
    });

  return res.put(data).$promise;
};
```

Remember that the interceptor it's defined on the main module, so all responseErrors are going through it.

Comment: are you sure your api returns a statusText property?

Comment: please provide your API implementation

Comment: AFAIK, statusText should come from AngularJS. Isnt it? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: The `statusText` doesn't come from Angular JS; it's defined by the responses you send from your server.

Comment: Where is it defined? Checking the documentation it says that I can access the response body from the 'data' property. Where are we getting the status and statusText properties from? Headers? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http